# Converting date format from M/D/YYYY to Month D, YYYY

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, datepicker

A page on my SharePoint site has a Date field with a datepicker. The selected date is inputted in M/D/YYY format (eg, 5/7/2013).

But I need the date to display like this once the page is published: MAY 7, 2013.

Is there a way to accomplish this with jQuery?

Comment: you could parse the date and convert it as you want, use switch case to convert month to text eg 5th to may and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the datepicker only for this:

```
var date = $.datepicker.formatDate('MM d, yy', new Date());
alert(date);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6hwZW/)

**UPDATE**

```
var myDate = $("#datepickerID").datepicker('getDate');
var date = $.datepicker.formatDate('MM d, yy', new Date(myDate));
alert(date);
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
function GetNewDate(myDate) {
    var date = $.datepicker.formatDate('MM d, yy', new Date(myDate));
    return date;
}
```

Also, set the p like this:

```
$('p').text(GetNewDate(date));
```

Comment: So if after publishing the page I had <p> 5/7/2013 </p>, could I do something like: var date = $.datepicker.formatDate('MM d, yy', new Date()); $('p').text().replaceWith(date);      ?

Comment: You can simply do: `$('p').text(date);`

Comment: Actually, this solution ALWAYS displays the current date. My page contains multiple dates, and now they're all taking the current date. But this will never be the case - can the code be modified to display the date the user selected in the datepicker?

Comment: Now all dates are displaying as December 31, 1969

Comment: What's your requirement? Does the code now display the date the user selected in the datepicker?

Comment: The user selects a date for their article. This date is published in a <p>, e.g., 12/9/1984. I then need to convert this date to display as December 9, 1984. The function should work not with a specific date, but any date.

Comment: Entered this into console and got the same: var myDate = $('.datePicker').datepicker('getDate');
function GetNewDate(myDate) {
    var date = $.datepicker.formatDate('MM d, yy', new Date(myDate));
    return date;
}
$('.datePicker').text(GetNewDate(date));

Comment: Do this: `var myDate = $('.datePicker').datepicker('getDate'); function GetNewDate(myDate) { var date = $.datepicker.formatDate('MM d, yy', new Date(myDate)); return date; } $('.datePicker').text(GetNewDate(myDate)); `